# How do I change the options in one ComboBox depending on another ComboBox?

Tags: vb.net, combobox

I am creating a windows form, in this form I have two Combo Boxes that I want to be linked together, meaning when I select one item in the first combo box (Category), it will change the items in the other combo box (Item) accordingly. I have no code behind it at the moment because I am unsure of how to begin.[image: Example] The image is off the form, if it helps in any way for you understanding what I need to happen then its there. I've been on different sites trying to read about how to do it but I am just completely lost. If anyone can point me in the right direction then that would be much appreciated[image: ![Example2] I now get this error whenever I run it and i'm not sure how to fix it, I am not sure what to put in these brackets 'If cmbCat.SelectedItem() Then'
No matter what I seem to put nothing works.

Public Class frmRestaurantOrd

```
Public Shared cmbCatDrinks As String = "Drinks"

Public Shared cmbCatMain As String = "Main"

Private Sub cmbCat_SelectedIndexChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles cmbCat.SelectedIndexChanged
    If cmbCat.SelectedItem() Then
        cmbItem.Items.Add("Water")
        cmbItem.Items.Add("Orange Juice")
        cmbItem.Items.Add("Coca Cola")
        cmbItem.Items.Add("Beer")
    ElseIf cmbCat.SelectedItem("Main") Then
        cmbItem.Items.Add("Piza 1")
    Else cmbCat.SelectedItem.Equals("")
        cmbItem.Items.Clear()
    End If
End Sub

Private Sub frmRestaurantOrd_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    cmbCat.Items.Add(cmbCatDrinks)
    cmbCat.Items.Add(cmbCatMain)
End Sub
```

Comment: Double-click the first combo box, it should open the code window for the selection event, in there you'll want to clear the second combo box and fill it based on the selected item in the first combo box

Comment: Can you list a couple of commands that would be used for that? It would be really helpful, and then I can trial and error until I figure it out.

Comment: With the Category ComboBox selected in the designer, click on the lightning bolt icon in the Properties window to show the events for a ComboBox. Then double-click on the ComboBox to the right of SelectedIndexChanged to create a handler for that event. Add code to the handler to get the current selection and add items to the other ComboBox.

Comment: Begin at the beginning.  Write code. Post a question *after* you are stuck and need help with the code.

Comment: But how am I to do that if I don't know what code to even begin using? I can't just ignore this either, it's needed for an assignment

Comment: It's needed for your assignment? Oh jeez, then, we will get right on it!

Comment: I'm not trying to be a dick, I know you all have better questions out there to answer, all i'm wanting to know is how I would go about this task? What commands are essential for it etc...

Comment: @ChaseRocker gave you something to try in the first comment. Did you try that?

Comment: I attempted that, I edited my post and put the code in, I think some what of it makes sense? But I honestly have no idea.

Comment: `If cmbCat.SelectedItem = "Drinks" Then`  Check if it's null first, though.

Comment: You're a life saver! Thank you aha, finally after so long of trying, I have done it!

Answer (score 0):

I would encourage you separate your data from the logic. What I mean by that is create a separate class for each selection category so that you will end up with three lists:

`List(Of Category)` 'This list will contain the two category of choices: Drink, MainDish

`List(Of Drink)` 'This list will contains the choices of drinks

`List(Of MainDish)` 'This list will contain the choices of main dishes

I would avoid using "Main" as the name of a class or List

Then, based on the choice a user makes in your combo box cmbCat, set the cmbItem  DataSource property to one list or the other.

Pseudo code:
cmbItem.DataSource = IIf(cmbCat.SelectedIndex == 0, Drinks, MainDish)